# Linear algebra proof if $A$ is $n\times n$ matrix then $\det(A^T)=\det(A)$

Tags: linear-algebra

**if $A$ is  $n\times n$ (square) matrix then $\det(A^T)=\det(A)$**

I am not sure how to prove this except on a case by case basis.

For example on 2x2 matrix

Let $A= \begin{bmatrix}
A& B  \\
C&D \\
\end{bmatrix}
$

then $A^T= \begin{bmatrix}
A& C   \\
B&D \\
\end{bmatrix}
$

$\det(AB-BC)=\det(AD-CB)$

But is there any simple way to show this theorem is not false. Not too complex of a proof to show this statement.

the definition of determinant I am using is

it is for $n\ge2$ the determinant of an nxn matrix $A=[a_{ij}]$ is the sum of the n terms of the form plus or minus $a_{ij}$ with plus or minus signs alternating where the entries

$a_{11},a_{12},......,a_{1n}$

are from the first row of A.

Comment: Use the Jordan canonical form. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jordan_normal_form

Comment: What is your working definition of $\det$? It maybe useful to edit your post to explain that.

Comment: @KimJongUn it is for $n\ge2$ the determinant of an nxn matrix A=[aij] is the sum of the n terms of the form plus or minus $a_(ij)$ with plus or minus signs alternating where the entries $a_11$ $a_22 a_1n$ are from the first row of A.

Comment: Thanks. Could you add that to the original post? Enclose LaTeX expressions between $\$$ and $\$$.

Comment: Well I know the theorem is true for $kxk$ matrix so I could do n=k+1 and use induction as nxn is a set of natural numbers.

Comment: You just need to prove that a permutation $\pi$ has the same sign as $\pi^{-1}$.